# How to access 2D numpy array elements along axis 1 using an array of indices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let `N` be a numpy array of shape `(m,n)` and `A` be an array of indices `(m,)` containing values between 0 and `n-1` including.

If I `i` is an index in range from 0 to m-1 including, then I want to access elements `N[i,A[i]]`.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

m = 2000
n = 10

N = np.zeros((m,n))
A = np.random.choice(n, m)

N[???, A] = 1
```

I expect the example code above to generate an array N of shape `(m,n)` initially with all zeros, and then set `N[i,j]=1` where `A[i]=j`.

I tried `N[:, A]=1`, but instead it changes all the elements of the array `N` to 1, which is not what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `:` indexes all the rows, so doing `N[:,A] = 1` is telling numpy to take all the rows and in column `A` set the value to 1. You want to just have a one-to-one row and column selection. The simplest way to do that is to use `np.arange`.

```py
N[np.arange(m), A] = 1
```

Now, each value in A has a corresponding row, which results in `m` row and column selections.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your condition `N[i,j]=1 where A[i] == j` as follows:

```
# Using conditional selection 
condition = np.arange(m) == A
N[condition] = 1
```